# display image devexpress gridview, is this a rocket science?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

Let say I have ViewModel which I use in devexpress gridview. Inside that view I display my data in devexpress gridview like this

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "myGridView";
        settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";
....
    var column = settings.Columns.Add("Id", "Id");
    column = settings.Columns.Add("Title", "MyTitle");
    ...    
    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

My Model is of IEnumerable
and everything is ok with this code up.
Now I want to display image inside that gridview before or after Id column.
So I found that this should be done with `Html.DevExpress().BinaryImage()`
But I'm stuck here for a while now.
First to describe my viewmodel and how my images are stored.
My Model have `List<Photo>` collection. I'm getting images as `FileContentResult`.

So I know I should use this `Html.DevExpress().BinaryImage()` but I dont know.
Here is example which I should follow.

```
column = settings.Columns.Add("", "Photos");
        Html.DevExpress().BinaryImage(
            imageSettings =>
            {
                //imageSettings.Name = "Photo";
                imageSettings.Width = 100;
                imageSettings.Height = 100;
            })
            .Bind(((System.Data.Linq.Binary)DataBinder.Eval(Model, "Photo")).ToArray())
            .Render();
```

**Update:**
I think I should try with this solution. Problem here is that I want to display in my grid first image from the Photos collection. I tried with with code below but with no luck. No errors.

```
var photoColumn = settings.Columns.Add("Photos[0].ImageData", "Foto");
        photoColumn.Visible = true;
        photoColumn.Width = 20;
        photoColumn.FieldName = "Photo.ImageData";
        photoColumn.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.BinaryImage;
        DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.BinaryImageEditProperties properties = (DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.BinaryImageEditProperties)photoColumn.PropertiesEdit;
        properties.ImageHeight = 50;
        properties.ImageWidth = 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use BinaryImage within the GridView directly, because [MVCxGridViewColumnType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcMVCxGridViewColumnTypeEnumtopic) supports BinaryImage.
Related link - [GridView - How to load binary image within BinaryImage column](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q340340.aspx)

Please, also review the [Grid View - Templates](http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/Templates) demo that demonstrates how to use the BinaryImage within the data rows.

Answer (score 0):

In you case it is necessary to customize DataItemTemplate and customize BinaryImage inside it as follows:

```
settings.Columns.Add(column => {
    column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c => {
        Html.DevExpress().BinaryImage(
            imageSettings => {
                imageSettings.Name = "Photo" + c.KeyValue;
                imageSettings.Width = 50;
                imageSettings.Height = 50;
            })
            .Bind(Here_Your_Code_To_Retrieve_Image_From_Current_DataItem)
            .Render();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that worked for me.

```
   settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
        {
            Html.DevExpress().BinaryImage(
                imageSettings =>
                {
                    imageSettings.Name = "PhotographOfCommodity" + c.KeyValue;
                    imageSettings.Width = 50;
                    imageSettings.Height = 50;
                })
                .Bind(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "PhotographOfCommodity")).Render();
        });
    });
```

HOPE THIS HELPS